# INSERTED NULL into Date and now cannot update

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

SQL Server 2014 issue.  I created a table which has two DATE columns with DATE datatypes.  One is populated the other is a future event.  I created a constraint that date1 < date2.  I inserted into the table putting NULL into date2 because it is future.  I cannot update anything in the table.  When trying to update date2 with date, I get Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date.  I tried entering date with and without apostrophes in ever way I could think of.  I cannot drop or alter the column because of the constraint I added.  HELP.  Please be specific about the SQL syntax needed for altering or updating to fix.

Comment: Can you share the statement you tried using?

Answer (score 0):

Change the constraint!  It is never true -- either false or `NULL`.  So, remove the constraint you have and do something like:

```
alter table t add constraint chk_t_date1_date2 check ( (date1 < date2) or date2 is null);
```

To drop the constraint, you do:

```
alter table t drop constraint <constraint name>;
```

You need to know the name of the constraint, which you can get from `information_schema.table_constraints`.

Comment: I dropped the constraint successfully.  I added the new one with OR IS NULL.  I still cannot update that column however. Same incompatibility.  I tried it without any constraint and cannot update the field as string or as date.  Here's my syntax UPDATE PET SET DeceasedDate = 2017-04-02 WHERE PetID=3

Comment: I think the issue is with a trigger I have running not the date field itself.  Thanks everyone!

Comment: @KathleenSheehan . . . The issue would have been *both* the trigger and the constraint.  Of course, the trigger doesn't get fired until the insert makes it passed the constraint.

Answer (score 0):

You should use single quotes '2019-04-18' with the ' before and after.

Comment: As nice as the advice, OP mentioned there are NULL values in date2. SQL Server does not treat the value as empty but rather unknown.  It will never evaluate correctly.